# jquery validate errorplacement with a specific place

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i want to validate my form with jquery validate but i want to put my error label to a specific place. an example below show error label put in the `<span class="error_label"></span>`. my question is how can i make errorplacement with a specific place, with an example below, please help me..thanks?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#fm_regis").validate({
    rules :{
        name: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {      
        //$(element).next('span .error_label :first').html(error);
        //$('.error_label').html(error);
        //$('.error_label').html(error);
        $(element).closest('.error_label').html(error);
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Please input a username",
        },
    }
});
});
</script>

    <form name="fm_regis" id="fm_regis">
    <table>   
      <tr>
         <td width="100">Nama</td>
         <td>:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30"/></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
         <td width="100"></td>
         <td></td>
         <td><span class="error_label"></span></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
     <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific situation you can do something like this:

```
$(element).closest('tr').next().find('.error_label').html(error);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kqTQu/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("#fm_regis").validate({
  rules :{
    name: {
      required: true,
    },
  },   
  errorLabelContainer: "#id-of-your-specific-place",
  // More of your code
})
```

And get rid of the `errorPlacement:` function.

Comment: This is very useful! `errorPlacement:` doesn't allow to restore you error container (to empty) once validation is success. `errorLabelContainer:` works great.

Comment: cool! So tired of my multiple `if` statements in bloated `errorPlacement`, which adjust error positions when the input is radio group, select list, input in table cell...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood the question correctly, try to change this line

```
$(element).closest('.error_label').html(error);
```

to

```
$(element).append( "<span class="error_label">" + error + "</span>") ;
```

make sure that you remove all error labels before initiating validation

Comment: sorry if i make u confused i just want put a error label to bottom of element

Comment: In that case simply use div instead of span .... $(element).append( "<div class="error_label">" + error + "</div>") ;